# Avoiding multiple "OR's" in a SQL query

Tags: sql, db2, ddl, check-constraints

I have the following working SQL query that adds a constraint `MindestensEinKontakt_CHECK` to the table `KundenKontaktDaten`. The constrainst ensures that at least one of the attributes `Twitter_Id`, `Google_Id`, `Facebook_Id`, `Skype_Id`, and `Telefonnummer` is not null:

```
ALTER TABLE KundenKontaktDaten 
    ADD CONSTRAINT MindestensEinKontakt_CHECK 
        CHECK (Twitter_Id IS NOT NULL OR Google_Id IS NOT NULL OR 
               Facebook_Id IS NOT NULL OR Skype_Id IS NOT NULL OR 
               Telefonnummer IS NOT NULL);
```

I want to avoid the multiple "OR's" and write the query in a more compact way. Is anyone aware of a way to do this?

Comment: You can use COALESCE (a, b,c,d...) is not null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`coalesce` returns the first non-`null` argument, or `null` if they are all `null`s. You could utilize it in your `alter table` statement:

```sql
ALTER TABLE KundenKontaktDaten
ADD CONSTRAINT MindestensEinKontakt_CHECK 
CHECK (COALESCE(Twitter_Id, Google_Id, Facebook_Id, Skype_Id, Telefonnummer) IS NOT NULL);
```

Comment: Although note that this only shortens the _text_ of the statement, and isn't likely to change the query plan